# uninitialized constant UsersController::Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page (**mytestpage.html.erb**) located at `app/views/users/mytestpage.html.erb`.

I've created a new table in my database called "Categories".

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that lists all of the categories (:title string) on my mytestpage.html.erb page and I'm getting this error:

> uninitialized constant UsersController::Categories

Here is my **users_controller.rb**

```
def mytestpage
  @user = User.new
  @categories = Categories.new
end
```

And here is my **users/mytestpage.html.erb** file:

```
<%= form_for categories do |f| %> 
     <%= f.collection_select(:title, Categories.all, :title, :description) %>
     <% end %>
```

I assume that I wouldn't define @categories in my user_controller.rb (even though the file is located in my users folder - while I tried it, doing so throws me the same error).

Answer (score 1):

**1. Use the instance variable instead of a constant in your view at app/views/users/mytestpage.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for categories do |f| %> 
     <%= f.collection_select(:title, @categories, :title, :description) %>
<% end %>
```

You're currently referencing a [constant](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html) in the view. What you should be doing is referencing the instance variable that you've created in `users_controller.rb`

Instance variables are prefixed with @ and are made available in the view that corresponds with the controller action that they are defined in.

**2. Change your instance variable definition to this:**

```
@categories = Category.new
```

or

```
@categories = Category.all
```

Right now you've got it defined as Categories.new and I don't think that's what you want to do - that is likely also why you're getting the error.

(depending on what you want to do - I feel like you might want to show all of the categories in you select tag? correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Nice, a little explaination on why this is failing would make it a great answer though.

Comment: Yes, I do have it defined (same as you have above).

Comment: okay - have you tried changing `Categories.all` to `@categories` in your view file?

Comment: try modifying your instance variable definition (see update in my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103912/discussion-between-andrew-hendrie-and-brittany).

Comment: If your model file is `category.rb` you might also want to make sure `Categories.all` shouldn't be `Category.all`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't created a model file for your Categories table. Something as simple as this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Should do the trick.

You will notice that I have named the class Category instead of Categories and this is due to the fact that Rails expects class names in singular form (eg User instead of Users) as it can infer the pluralised table name from the singular class name.

Comment: category.rb exists in my model file

Comment: In that case it should be Category.new and Category.all. You only used the pluralised form when you are talking about a collection, eg User.categories

Comment: Also try changing it to: <%= form_for @categories